# Difficulties following lecture notes in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to follow some Lecture Notes from a course named Physics in Symmetry which deals with applications of Group Theory in Physics. I am at the chapter of Clebsch-Gordan decompositions of product representations.

In the lecture notes, the following statement is made:
The formula $D=\bigoplus_{\mu} a_{\mu}D^{(\mu)}$ together with the orthogonality of characters implies:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{[g]}\displaystyle\sum_{g \in G} \bigg|\chi^{(\mu \times \nu)}(g)\bigg|^{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}^{2}
\end{align}
where $D$ is the character of the representation, $D^{\mu}$ is the character of the irreps into which $D$ is decomposed, $\chi^{(\mu \times \nu)}(g)$ is the character of the product representation and [g] is the order of the group .

In order to prove this statement I have tried the following:

The formula $D=\bigoplus_{\mu} a_{\mu}D^{(\mu)}$ implies:

\begin{align}
\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)=\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu}(g) \tag{1}
\end{align}
Multiplying by $\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)^{*}$ and summing over all elements $g \in G$ one obtains:
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}\bigg|\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)\bigg|^{2}&=\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu}(g)\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)^{*} \\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu}(g)\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)^{*} \\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}\chi^{\mu}(g)\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)^{*} \\
\end{align}
Now I tried using the conjugate of relation (1) in the above equation which yields
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}\bigg|\chi^{\mu \times \nu}(g)\bigg|^{2}&=\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G}\chi^{\mu}(g)\displaystyle\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}^{*}\chi^{\mu}(g)^{*}
\end{align}
This is where I am stuck since I am unsure whether I can just rearrange the summation signs in order to be able to use the orthogonality of characters.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question regarding it. The sum you stated above, namely $\sum_{g \in G} \chi^{\rho}(g) \chi^{\nu}(g)^{*}$ would imply that $\chi^{\rho}$ is an irreducible rep, because of the orthogonality of characters, correct? Which would contradict the idea of decomposing the product rep in the first place. Also, does $\chi^{\rho}$ represent the character of the character $\rho(g)$?

Comment: The first problem is you are getting confused by the notation and using $\mu$
with two different meanings. I would recommend writing $\rho(g)$
for $\chi^{\mu \times \nu}$, to avoid being distracted by the irrelevant
superscript $\mu \times \nu$. You should know that, for irreducible characters
$\chi^\mu$ and $\chi^\nu$, the sum $\sum_{g \in G}\chi^\mu(g)\chi^\nu(g)$ 
 is equal to $|G|$ (not $|g|$) when $\mu = \nu$ and to $0$ otherwise.
The equation follows from that.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my comment, and I wrote $\chi^\rho$ instead of $\chi^\mu$ in one place. I have corrected that now. The characters $\chi^\mu$ and $\chi^\nu$ are assumed to be irreducible.

Comment: $|G|$ is the order of the group $G$ i.e. the number of elements in $G$. That is standard notation.

Comment: I still have trouble making up the argument. Using your suggestion I get that $\rho(g)=\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu}$. Now if I multiply with $\rho(g)^{*}$ I get on the right hand side of the sum $\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu} \rho(g)^{*}$. This results in the equality $\bigg|\rho(g)\bigg|^{2}=\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu} \rho(g)^{*}$. Which by taking the sum over all $g \in G$ leads me to $\sum_{g \in G}\bigg|\rho(g)\bigg|^{2}=\sum_{g \in G}\sum_{\mu}a_{\mu}\chi^{\mu} \rho(g)^{*}$.

Comment: When you multiply by $\rho(g)^*$, you should multiply by $\sum_{\mu}a_\mu^*\chi^{\mu *}$. Then you can use the orthogonality relations.